# `tcolorbox` and `tabularx` - toprule and settings conflict

Tags: color, tabularx, tcolorbox

While transforming some `tabularx` tables into tcolorboxed ones I found that `tcolorbox` does many things which are not "authorized", but not to turn off. F.i. it changes the general rule color for the table and the arraystretch. Using a customized `booktabs` setup this really destructs consistency.

The main two issues I already mentioned. Therefore two questions (I haven't found any settings in the manual):

- How can one turn off the change of the rule color in a not-workaround way? Doing the change twice (once by `tcolorbox` and once by using `before upper app`) can't be a good solution.
- How can one turn off the change of the `arraystretch`? I haven't found any good solution. Do I really have to patch one of those internal tcolorbox macros?

And what would be very nice too:

- I do not want to change all tables concerning content. So I would really appreciate a workaround to be able to use a first line of the table starting with `\toprule` (currently results in errors and I use a tcolorbox rule).

To illustrate the problem:

[image: table problem]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}

\def\tabletitle#1{%
    \refstepcounter{table}Table\ \thetable\ --\ #1%
    \addcontentsline{lot}{section}{#1}%
}
\newtcolorbox{tablebox}[3][]{
    enhanced, sharp corners=all,colback=white,colframe=white,tabularx={#2},title={\tabletitle{#3}},label=#1,attach boxed title to top right={xshift=1cm,yshift=-2mm},before upper app={\arrayrulecolor{black}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}{lX}
  \toprule \textbf{Stufe} & \textbf{Name}\\\midrule
    -1 & Teil\\
  0 & Kapitel\\
    1 & Abschnitt\\
    2 & Unterabschnitt\\
    3 & Unterunterabschnitt\\
    4 & Absatz\\
    5 & Unterabsatz\\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\captionof{table}{Test}

\begin{tablebox}{lX}{Test}
  \textbf{Stufe} & \textbf{Name}\\\midrule%\toprule
    -1 & Teil\\
  0 & Kapitel\\
    1 & Abschnitt\\
    2 & Unterabschnitt\\
    3 & Unterunterabschnitt\\
    4 & Absatz\\
    5 & Unterabsatz\\\bottomrule
\end{tablebox}
\end{document}
```

---

*Update:* The code that causes all those problems (options set by `tabularx` key):

```
boxsep=\z@,top=\z@,bottom=\z@,leftupper=\z@,rightupper=\z@,
toptitle=1mm,bottomtitle=1mm,boxrule=0.5mm,
before upper={\arrayrulecolor{tcbcol@frame}\def\arraystretch{1.1}#1%
   \tcb@hack@currenvir\tabularx{\linewidth}{#2}},
after upper=\endtabularx\arrayrulecolor{black}},
```

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No, that's one of the problems. Probably that's hooked anywhere in the before upper code, but even renewing in `before upper app` does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gave an answer yourself, but you also wrote that you do not think that your question is answered with it. I do not see, why not.

Anyway, since you asked for a less invasive way, I can give two alternatives. Both alternatives do not use `tcolorbox` for the top rule, but insert a `\toprule` where it does not hurt.

- `tableboxA` is quite similar to your own answer, but defines a `mytablarx*` instead of redefining `tabularx*`. Note `\toprule\let\toprule\relax` for my top rule alternative.
- `tableboxB` does not need a redefined `tabularx*` or a `mytabularx*` which both use some internal code. Array stretch and array rule color are set directly. In your question you expressed that defining the color twice is not a good solution... But, well, it is a solution and I figure it is not a bad solution either...

In my eyes, the only annoying thing is that `\toprule` cannot be used directly as one would expect. Here, we need a workaround like in your answer or in mine, but adjusting color and array stretch (even twice) is more or less harmless:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}

\makeatletter
\tcbset{%
  mytabularx*/.style 2 args={%
    boxsep=\z@,top=\z@,bottom=\z@,leftupper=\z@,rightupper=\z@,
    toptitle=1mm,bottomtitle=1mm,boxrule=0pt,
    before upper={#1\tcb@hack@currenvir\tabularx{\linewidth}{#2}\toprule\let\toprule\relax},            % through deleting: solve the arraystretch and color issue
    after upper=\endtabularx}
}
\makeatother

\newtcolorbox[use counter*=table]{tableboxA}[3][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw, sharp corners=all, colback=white,colframe=black,
  title={Table\ \thetable\ --\ #3},list text={#3},add to list={lot}{section},label=#1,
  mytabularx*={}{#2},
  attach boxed title to top right={xshift=1cm,yshift=2mm},
}

\newtcolorbox[use counter*=table]{tableboxB}[3][]{%
  blank, sharp corners=all, colback=white,colframe=black,
  title={Table\ \thetable\ --\ #3},list text={#3},add to list={lot}{section},label=#1,
  tabularx*={\arrayrulecolor{black}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}}{#2},
  before upper app={\toprule\let\toprule\relax},
  boxrule=0pt,
  attach boxed title to top right={xshift=1cm,yshift=2mm},
}

\begin{document}

\captionof{table}{Test}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
  \toprule \textbf{Stufe} & \textbf{Name}\\\midrule
    -1 & Teil\\
    0 & Kapitel\\
    1 & Abschnitt\\
    2 & Unterabschnitt\\
    3 & Unterunterabschnitt\\
    4 & Absatz\\
    5 & Unterabsatz\\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\vskip2\baselineskip

\begin{tableboxA}{lX}{Test}
  \toprule \textbf{Stufe} & \textbf{Name}\\\midrule
    -1 & Teil\\
    0 & Kapitel\\
    1 & Abschnitt\\
    2 & Unterabschnitt\\
    3 & Unterunterabschnitt\\
    4 & Absatz\\
    5 & Unterabsatz\\\bottomrule
\end{tableboxA}

\vskip2\baselineskip

\begin{tableboxB}{lX}{Test}
  \toprule \textbf{Stufe} & \textbf{Name}\\\midrule
    -1 & Teil\\
    0 & Kapitel\\
    1 & Abschnitt\\
    2 & Unterabschnitt\\
    3 & Unterunterabschnitt\\
    4 & Absatz\\
    5 & Unterabsatz\\\bottomrule
\end{tableboxB}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I really like tableboxB. Probably I missed the typical configurable `tcolorbox` style with keys for nearly everything.

Comment: @TeXnician Yes, the `tabularx` key is some kind of *special application* key which I added to the `tcolorbox` core, because of the `\tcb@hack@currenvir` trick. The color and arrayrule settings are coming from my own applications - possibly too specialized ...

Comment: Maybe that's an idea for the next update to be able to change that behavior (a key for document defaults would be sufficient I think). But that's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a workaround (if anyone knows a less invasive way, please post it here). It does explicitly NOT solve the question. What it does:

- redefining the `tabularx` style to kick out every unwanted and unneeded piece of code and
- letting `\toprule` to `\relax` and then emulating the toprule with the box rules

[image: tablex]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}

\makeatletter
\tcbset{%
  tabularx*/.style 2 args={%
    boxsep=\z@,top=\z@,bottom=\z@,leftupper=\z@,rightupper=\z@,
    toptitle=1mm,bottomtitle=1mm,boxrule=0pt, toprule=1pt, top=2.25pt,        % "solve" toprule issue (i)
    before upper={#1\tcb@hack@currenvir\tabularx{\linewidth}{#2}},            % through deleting: solve the arraystretch and color issue
    before upper app = {\let\toprule\relax},                                  % "solve" toprule issue (ii)
    after upper=\endtabularx}
}
\makeatother

\newtcolorbox[use counter*=table]{tablebox}[3][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw, sharp corners=all, colback=white,colframe=black,
  title={Table\ \thetable\ --\ #3},list text={#3},add to list={lot}{section},label=#1,
  tabularx*={}{#2},
  attach boxed title to top right={xshift=1cm,yshift=2mm},
}

\begin{document}

\captionof{table}{Test}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
  \toprule \textbf{Stufe} & \textbf{Name}\\\midrule
    -1 & Teil\\
    0 & Kapitel\\
    1 & Abschnitt\\
    2 & Unterabschnitt\\
    3 & Unterunterabschnitt\\
    4 & Absatz\\
    5 & Unterabsatz\\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\vskip2\baselineskip

\begin{tablebox}{lX}{Test}
  \toprule \textbf{Stufe} & \textbf{Name}\\\midrule
    -1 & Teil\\
    0 & Kapitel\\
    1 & Abschnitt\\
    2 & Unterabschnitt\\
    3 & Unterunterabschnitt\\
    4 & Absatz\\
    5 & Unterabsatz\\\bottomrule
\end{tablebox}
\end{document}
```